# Why doesn't my named route work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

Standard MVC 5 template.
So I'm trying to understand and create a named route to be used like:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "myroute",  routeValues: new { code = "123" })">this link</a>
```

In the Home Controller:

```
[Route("Home/DoIt", Name = "myroute"), HttpGet]
public ActionResult DoIt(string code)
{
  return View();
}
```

MvcAttributeRouting is of course enabled in RoutConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Because if it wasn't enabled, one will get:

> A route named 'myroute' could not be found in the route collection.
>   Parameter name: name

But I am getting:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Home/DoIt

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Obviously, I'm doing something wrong with the Route attribute, because even this doesn't work:

```
  [Route("DoIt")]
```

or

```
[Route("Home/DoIt")]
```

Both give me 404, regardless of the request URL being http://localhost/Home/DoIt or http://localhost/DoIt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***order*** in which you place the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` line is important. You have it in the wrong location. It must be called before the default route.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Add this to get attribute routes to work
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Routing works like a switch case statement. The *first* match wins. But if you put the default route first, it will match every URL with 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments and effectively override any attribute routes of those lengths.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#enabling-attribute-routing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing to your action directly from the browser? I mean YourHost/Home/DoIt. If it also raises a 404 error then your problem probably arises from your route config.

Maybe you don't have route attribute configuration enabled. Check the following:
From MSDN:

> To enable attribute routing, call MapMvcAttributeRoutes during
>   configuration.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```